# Adding animation to my images with JQuery

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is my home page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Home/Home.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="IndicationContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<table id="home" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <td id="homeLinks">
        <div style="padding-left:35px;" id="homeListing" class="containerMid">
            <div id="homeView">
                <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;">
                    <tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="btnIcOld" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                                <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Load.png")%>" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="btnIc" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                                <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Bar_Chart.png")%>" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="btnPricing" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                                <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Pie_Chart_disabled.png")%>" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="btnSheets" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                                <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Line_Chart_disabled.png")%>" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="btnPort" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                                <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Modify_disabled.png")%>" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="btnAdmin" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                                <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/Profile_disabled.png")%>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="Td1">
                                <b>Indications Calculator | </b>
                            </td>
                            <td id="lblIc">
                                <b>Indications Calculator - Beta | </b>
                            </td>
                            <td id="lblPricing">
                                <b>Managing Pricing Triggers | </b>
                            </td>
                            <td id="lblSheets">
                                <b>Creating Pricing Sheets | </b>
                            </td>
                            <td id="lblPort">
                                <b>Portfolio Analysis | </b>
                            </td>
                            <td id="lblAdmin">
                                <b>Administration</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</table>

<div id="pageMessage"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnIc').live('click', function () {
            window.location.href = "<%=Url.Action("Indications") %>";
        });

        $('#btnIcOld').live('click', function () {
            window.location.href = 'https://extranetint/swap';
        });

        $('#btnPricing').live('click', function () {
            //window.location.href = "<%=Url.Action("Triggers") %>";
        });

        $('#btnSheets').live('click', function () {
            //window.location.href = "<%=Url.Action("Sheets") %>";
        });

        $('#btnPort').live('click', function () {
            //window.location.href = "<%=Url.Action("Analysis") %>";
        });

        $('#btnAdmin').live('click', function () {
            //window.location.href = "<%=Url.Action("Admin") %>";
        });

    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

How can I, with JQuery (or really anything), achieve a mouse-over effect on my images where they will grow a little bit as you hover over them? I tried using JQuery animate but for some reason I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your jquery code?  (preferably at http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can tinker on it)

Comment: I tried using this with no result - http://jsfiddle.net/5jYwQ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a hover event to all the img tags in your page or just the ones that is required and use 2 functions to animate the size for mousein and mouseout

```
$(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            height: '110%',
            width: '110%',
        });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I reformatted the code substantially so that it can be correctly displayed as code. Please use only spaces to indent code lines, and indent all lines by at least four spaces so that it is recognized as a code block. You might want to extend this answer with some explanation of what it is doing and how to go with the code.

Comment: Thanks Will try to follow the instructions

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really care about Internet Explorer, you can just use a bit of CSS3.

```
#homeView img {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
#homeView img:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

When the user hovers the image, the image will be zoomed in. Works with the current version of Chrome, Safari, Opera and the upcoming Firefox 4. In Firefox 3.5 and 3.6 you will see the zoom-in effect, just without the transitions.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thai/WNmdh/1/

Comment: i like this solution, its pretty sexy.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this site](http://www.purexnaturalelements.ca/) that uses a growing effect.

Comment: I would like something that worked on the code I actually have. If I have to refactor the code around then I'll take that task up at a later time. I was wondering if there was any way though to apply it to the specific way I have my menu set up, within tables and such.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think your main problem was with using `.btnIc` instead of `#btnIc`. Also, you are targeting the `td` instead of the `img` inside it. Here's a working example with `div`s instead of a `td` and an `img`: http://jsfiddle.net/zyKde/

If you want it to work on your code, you should change `$('#btnIc .img')` to `$('#btnIc img')` in the javascript code.

(Edit) also, make sure you set the correct `position: relative` and `position: absolute` on your `td` and `img`, if you want to use `top` and `left`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial for exactly what you want [here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/popout-details-on-hover-w-css/) - pretty much works the same way as your jsfiddle paste. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `class="btnIc"` attribute to your image(s) and your jQuery example will work.